# How to convert character(0) to NA in a list?

Tags: r, list

How can `character(0)` be converted to `NA` in a list?

Example:

```
a = list("a", character(0), "b", "c")
```

to

```
a = list("a", NA, "b", "c")
```

Comment: like: `lapply(a, function(x) if (x == 'character(0)') 'NA' else x)`??

Comment: Is it really a string that contains the phrase "character(0)"?

Comment: i suspect you've given us faulty inputs, and what you actually want is more like: `lapply(a, function(x)  if (!length(x) && is.character(x)) NA_character_ else x)`

Comment: Or is your data more along the lines of `list("a", character(0), "b", "c")`

Comment: with of course the caveat that you should acknowledge that `character(0)` is in general different from `NA_character_`...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace `character(0)` only (assume you meant `character(0)` instead of `"character(0)"`):

```
a = list("a", character(0), "b", "c")

lapply(a, function(x) if(identical(x, character(0))) NA_character_ else x)

#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[3]]
#[1] "b"

#[[4]]
#[1] "c"
```

Replace all length-0 elements:

```
a[lengths(a) == 0] <- NA_character_

a
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[3]]
#[1] "b"

#[[4]]
#[1] "c"
```

Comment: It was perfect! Tks!

Answer (score 4):

`a[a=="character(0)"] <- "NA"`

Given your example this provides what you ask for, but is that actually what you want, though?

Answer (score 0):

4 years later but...

As `character(0)` is class character, working with same class would be recommended.

Instead of `lapply()` or `purrr::map()`, as the list already exists, perhaps `purrr::modify()` is a best fit.

```
a <- purrr::modify_if(
    a, 
    ~ length(.) == 0, 
    ~ NA_character_
  )
```

Note that you can use `~ NA`, `~ NA_character_` or other `NA` types.

The benefit from this approach is that you can change (map o modify) a list by depth (`map_depth`), logical condition (`map_if`) or directly at some elements (`map_at`), and is quite easy to read.

See `purrr` family functions to handle lists. https://purrr.tidyverse.org/