# Look up value based on partial string match in R

Tags: r

I have a table (table 1) with a bunch of cities (punctuation, capitalization and spaces have been removed).

I want to scan through the 2nd table (table 2) and pull out any record (the first) that exactly matches or contains the string anywhere within it.

```r
# Table 1
  city1    
1 waterloo 
2 kitchener
3 toronto  
4 guelph   
5 ottawa


# Table 2
  city2
1 waterlookitchener  
2 toronto  
3 hamilton  
4 cityofottawa
```

This would give the 3rd table seen below.

```r
# Table 3
  city1      city2
1 waterloo   waterlookitchener  
2 kitchener  waterlookitchener  
3 toronto    toronto  
4 guelph     <N/A>  
5 ottawa     cityofottawa
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are more sophisticated ways of completing your task, but here is a simple approach using `tidyverse`.

```r
df <- read_table2("city1
waterloo
kitchener
toronto
guelph
ottawa")

df2 <- read_table2("city2
waterlookitchener
toronto
hamilton
cityofottawa")

df3 <- df$city1 %>% 
  lapply(grep, df2$city2, value=TRUE) %>%
  lapply(function(x) if(identical(x, character(0))) NA_character_ else x) %>%
  unlist

df3 <- cbind(df, df3)
```

1. Search for every element of `df$city1` in `df2$city2` (partial or complete match) and return this element of `df2$city2`. See `?grep` for more information.
2. Replace the `character(0)` (element not found) with `NA`. See [How to convert character(0) to NA in a list with R language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44766349/how-to-convert-character0-to-na-in-a-list-with-r-language) for details.
3. Convert list into a vector (`unlist`).
4. Attach result to list of cities (`cbind`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `fuzzyjoin`. In this case, you can use the function `stri_detect_fixed` from `stringi` package to identify at least one occurrence of a fixed pattern in a string.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

fuzzy_right_join(table2, table1, by = c("city2" = "city1"), match_fun = stri_detect_fixed) %>% 
  select(city1, city2)
```

**Output**

```
      city1             city2
1  waterloo waterlookitchener
2 kitchener waterlookitchener
3   toronto           toronto
4    guelph              <NA>
5    ottawa      cityofottawa
```

**Data**

```
table1 <- structure(list(city1 = c("waterloo", "kitchener", "toronto", 
"guelph", "ottawa")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

table2 <- structure(list(city2 = c("waterlookitchener", "toronto", "hamilton", 
"cityofottawa")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```